# "Me" or "Myself"- which one is correct here?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it correct to use “yourself” and “myself” (versus “you” and “me”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me)

> you and ***myself/me*** will enjoy the function being arranged in
>   honor of the new principal.

"Me" or "Myself"- which one is correct here and why?

Comment: A very similar question has been asked [here: When to use me or myself](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/when-to-use-me-or-myself). The answers are very interesting.

Comment: @Irene: Thanks for the reference. I am aware of the rules of the emphatic/reflexive pronouns. I think 'me' is appropriate here, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Foool, You and I will ...

Comment: One more reference to add to the previous one:[You and I OR you and me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those you presented is correct. The correct sentence would be:

> You and I will enjoy the function being arranged in honor of the new principal.

Comment: A trick that usually works in cases like this is to temporarily ignore the other half and see which word works. So, would you say "I will ...", "Me will ...", or "Myself will ...". Since it's "I will", it's "You and I will".

Comment: I down-voted. See my answer as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Subject / Nominative: You and I

E.g. You and I will go to the cinema. (where you and I are the ones doing)

Object / Accusative: You and me

E.g. The shopkeeper served you and me promptly. (where you and I are having something done to us)

Reflexive: We hurt ourselves / I hurt myself while playing football. (when you and I are doing something to ourselves - contrast "He hurt ME (never 'myself')" with "I hurt MYSELF (never 'me')")

Answer (score 0):

In my practice I have always said "You and me". I did it so often that get used to it, and nobody corrected me.)

Comment: I've up-voted. See my answer as to why.

Answer (score -3):

Both are correct, but unless you want to be emphatic, use “me”.

The sentence, “You and me will enjoy the function being arranged in honor of the new principal” is an abbreviation for the sentence, “The party consisting of you and me will enjoy the function being arranged in honor of the new principal”, and, as such, is completely grammatical, the “you” and “me” both being objects of the preposition “of”. If abbreviations are not recognized and taken into account as such, an endless train of anomalies and paradoxes results.

Of course, the “You and I” version is also grammatical, but it is not synonymous with the “You and me” version. The “You and me” sentence is more restricted in meaning, with the implication of “togetherness” that cannot be inferred, but only presumed, from the “You and I” version. Maybe we’re not attending to go as a pair to the function, be we happen to know that each of us will be at the function (each with some other partner, perhaps).

Consider the sentence, “Me and her want to go shopping together this afternoon.” The “together” in this sentence is pretty much redundant, or present only for the sake of emphasis. However, if I say, “She and I want to go shopping this afternoon,” you might very plausibly inquiry, “Together?” – that is, she and I may be going on separate shopping trips. In that case, putting in the word “together”, if indeed that is what is intended, is necessary: “She and I want to go shopping together this afternoon.”

For a starker example, saying, “She and I are married” leaves you open to the query, “To each other?”, accompanied by titters of laughter from those around, but saying “Me and her and married” goes a long way to obviate that query.

Comment: By your logic, it should be "Me and her *wants* to go", since the phrase is an abbreviation for 'The party consisting of...' It isn't. That may be what you intend, but your listeners will naturally conclude you don't know the difference between *I* and *me*.

Comment: @TimLymington: You bring up a point that I did not address explicitly, but your analysis is wrong. The correct analysis is that, because foreground items will (because of a gut feel for what is linguistically comfortable to the ordinary, unreflective language-user) always be consistent among themselves, the verb will always agree with whatever is APPARENTLY the subject in foreground (as opposed to agreeing with the ACTUAL subject that is in the background).