# You are myself, you are I, or you are me?

Tags: grammar

I am translating a text from Arabic about a woman talking to the ghost of her dead husband and saying something that translates literally to ''You are I.'' I would like to know the difference between the three forms mentioned above and if any of them is grammatically wrong.

Comment: There is some relevant information on the following pages: [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313), [“That was me” vs. “That was I”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143363), [When to use “me” or “myself”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20151)

Comment: On the face of it, I'd guess that either "You are myself" or "you are me" would be better than "you are I" but that's from an English perspective.

Did you notice how much more flexibility Ararbic treats number and gender, and that that makes 'You are I' without context almost meaningless'?

Answer (score -1):

i am you. you are me. me is you. yourself is i. and yes, you just so happpened to ask the pinnacle of problematic understanding within the english language. lol. All of them are, as it goes. However, all would be accepted, due to the world wide use of american british, whatever that is.

Comment: I remember from my schoolgirl Latin that nouns in apposition ("A is B") both go in the nominative case. However, "You are I" might sound pretentiously over-correct. It depends on the tone of the passage.