# This is me singing (vs myself)

Tags: grammar

(I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question, and I apologize, but after reading the similar questions and answers, I'm still not exactly sure how to answer mine...)

I wrote the following sentence:

> I found some old raw footage of *me* singing [song-title-here] by [author-name-here].

I think that sentence should use "myself" instead of "me", but when I reduce the sentence, "me" seems better. For example,

> This video is of *me* singing.

sounds better to me than,

> This video is of *myself* singing.

Should the sentence I wrote use "me" or "myself", and is the answer the same in the shortened sentence?

Comment: Consider these sentences: (1) *This video is of **me** singing **to myself***. (2) *In this video, I sang **to myself**.* (3) *I **myself** made this video of **me** singing to **myself**.* In short, it should be *of **me** singing*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "me" or "myself"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/when-to-use-me-or-myself)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you! When you put it that way it seems so obvious. :)