# "People like you" versus "people like yourself"?

Tags: personal-pronouns, reflexives

In the latest South Park episode, I noticed a line:

> We have so many abandoned babies and
>   not enough people like **yourself** who
>   care.

Which kinda struck me, because I'd expect it to be *people like you*.

Is the original quote broken, or are both correct, representing a different meaning?

Comment: Damn I was meaning to ask this!  But in the more general sense, for example, I also hear things like 'This has already been discussed by Bob and myself.'

Comment: I guess "yourself" refers to the personality of a known person. I'm wondering about [Google Ngram result](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=people+like+you%2Cpeople+like+yourself&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Boob I don't understand what you mean by 'personality'?  The results in google book search give me the impression that it is an attempt to show respect where using the pronoun 'you' could feel too familiar.  Perhaps because we lack a formal 2nd person pronoun in English.

Comment: @z7sg: I mean e.g. "You will attract people like yourself" means "like yourself in personality and traits".

Comment: @Boob Ah yes that's the standard reflexive usage when the subject and object are the same person.  I love her. vs She loves herself.

Comment: Related to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/you-and-yourself-me-and-myself

Comment: Personally, I'd use "you" when discussing my perspective of the person, and "yourself" when discussing the person's perspective of his or her self. i.e., "I am comfortable around people like you." vs "You are comfortable around people like yourself."

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600425/2085).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find that [yourself](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/yourself_1) is

> **yourself**, pronoun
>
> <sup>1</sup> used when both the subject and object of the verb are you
> *Be careful with that knife or you'll cut yourself!*
>
> <sup>2</sup> used to give **special attention** to the subject of the sentence
> *Did you make the dress yourself?*
> *You can do that yourself.*

The second meaning is not *reflective* and does not require "you" to be previously mentioned. The meaning is simply **emphasized**, such as in:

*not stressed*

> people like you

vs *stressed*

> people like you yourself / people like yourself

**EDIT:**
Some further examples from Merriam-Webster's dictionary of English usage

> A secret, kept from all the rest / Between yourself and me. - Lewis Carroll, "She's All My Fancy Painted Him," ca. 1854
>
> Get me some good left-handers like yourself and Robinson - Robert Frost, letter, 23 Jan. 1921
>
> In all this I look to nothing but the happiness of yourself, Mr. Randolph, and the dear children - Thomas Jefferson, letter, 27 Feb. 1809
>
> Those who, like yourself, know what they are about - Walter W. Skeat, letter, in K. M. Elisabeth Murray, *Caught in the Web of Words*, 1977

**EDIT2**:
I feel that choice of the first dictionary might have been unlucky, here is [oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yourself?view=uk), where I think the distinction is made perfectly clear:

> <sup>1</sup> [reflexive] used to refer to the person being addressed as the object of a verb or preposition when they are also the subject of the clause
>
> <sup>2</sup> [emphatic] you personally (used to emphasize the person being addressed)

The way I read the second meaning is completely unrelated to the first; under second meaning it is not reflexive, simply the meaning of *yourself* is *you personally* (try to substitute phrase "you personally" instead of "yourself" in the four examples from the MW; I think it *does* make it clear and very precise and I think that this is a very good definition of actual usage).

Comment: Your examples of emphasis are different from the example from the OP because in yours the 2nd person pronoun is already present.

Comment: Actually the examples from http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/you-and-yourself-me-and-myself/1186#1186 are better, there is even direct mention of the form 'like myself' (so the only question is if replacing it with yourself is permitted).

Comment: Following it to http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PP1&ots=nYxRhjC3_3&dq=merriam-webster%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage&pg=PA647#v=snippet&q=yourself&f=false I would say that there is plenty of evidence.

Answer (score 2):

"Yourself" could have been used in a different way. "Yourself" can be used as an emphatic appositive  of you, as in "You yourself did it."
"Yourself" can also be used to refer to someone personally, like in the example you gave. However, "Yourself" is a reflexive pronoun, which means it must be preceded by a noun or pronoun which refers to it.

"You" is a pronoun that is used to address someone personally most of the time. Sometimes it is used to address several people, as in "You are all clever."

In this case, "youself" is being used in the same way as "you" : to refer to the person being talked to. There is no difference in meaning, and none of them are incorrect.

Comment: But you can't replace you by yourself everywhere.  For example, _"I'd like to speak to yourself."_ is definitely infelicitous.

Comment: I hope my edit to "yourself" explains it.

Comment: Can you reference #2?  I doubt this usage will appear in any grammar references.

Comment: Webster 1913 states: An emphasized or(!) reflexive form of the pronoun. Therefore it does not have to be reflexive if it is the emphasized form.

Comment: Neither reflexive nor emphasized: _myself presented to him a bronze sword_  I don't 'get' what it means though.

Comment: @z7sg, you quote was not complete: "Myself when re-conducting him respectfully to his ship presented to him a bronze sword" - not reflexive, emphasized!

Comment: @Unreason They left out the time clause for brevity.  It's still replacing the pronoun.  It feels wrong!  But it's TE Lawrence!  Also: _King Idomeneus and myself being the children of Deucalion, his son_.  Again no emphasis there, no reflexivity.  Oxford Dictionaries says it's _literary_ (So if I use it is it pretentious?)

Comment: @z7sg, ic, hm... First, I don't feel anything wrong with "I personally ... presented to him a bronze sword." (from 2nd meaning, oxford, straight replacement). As for literary, similar replacement is ok, but now it is confusing when to know which is which (before I employed simple logic - if not reflexive then emphasized, but now it seems that it so, unless literary when it can be a normal I, too)

Comment: @Unreason Yes,this is what I've been trying to say.  I think 'literary' means that it's OK for TE Lawrence to do it but if I say things like "Myself prefer smoked fish." then I will sound like a fool.

Comment: @z7sg, not to me, I know you are not TE, so I will apply second meaning: "You personally prefer smoked fish."

Comment: @Unreason OK, so it's good for EL&U but I shall try this out in the real world and see if I get any funny looks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever doubts arise, you may choose to stick with the most common usage and, usually, you'll be fine.

But a quick search reveals that **they're both correct**, meaning that such expressions exists. You can find a reference on the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/yourself), the third entry.

There is also a mention of such usage on the site [Perfect your English](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/grammar/reflexive-pronouns.htm).

Comment: Interesting that it's on OALD but not the Oxford Dictionaries search.  The OALD entry doesn't explain the meaning either.  What is the meaning?  Anyway, it may be accepted but I still hate it. :) To me it sounds... smarmy.

Comment: @z7sg: I couldn't find it elsewhere, but that example is quite the exact one the OP asked about, no? I quoted it  also considering that... I'm not the most expert and I still think that it's better in such cases to stick with the "official" usage, but I can't ignore the fact that it's listed in some important dictionary... Do you agree? (I'm asking seriously, not being sarcastic) :D

Comment: No I do agree... I think there is more to this than meets the eye as you can see from google books this is not a silly grammatical error but equally, it isn't correct to say that they are equivalent in meaning and usage.  Have you read nohat's answer? It's quite interesting:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/you-and-yourself-me-and-myself/1186#1186

Comment: @z7sg I read his answer, he confirmes that they're correct, no? Then... yes I agree, they're not completely interchangeable, but you see, my point was more "they're not wrong", rather than "use both whenever you like".

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, I'm not disagreeing with you as such, just looking for the ultimate definitive answer!

Comment: @z7sg: Ok ok :D