# "I", "me" and "myself"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, reflexives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends)
>   [Can “myself” stand for both “me” and “I” in “my mother and I/me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73008/can-myself-stand-for-both-me-and-i-in-sentences-like-this)

What is correct?
We are a family of four: my father, my mother, my brother and me.
or
We are a family of four: my father, my mother, my brother and I.
or
We are a family of four: my father, my mother, my brother and myself.

Comment: For *me* vs. *I*, see these two most excellent answers: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655). For *I/me* vs. *myself*, see the other linked question. Have a look at the questions linked from there, too, or browse the tags ["pronouns"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns) and ["reflexives"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflexives). This subject has been covered extensively on this site.

Answer (score 5):

All are correct—they differ only in style. The choice of *I* or *me* usually depends on whether the pronoun in question is part of the *subject* or *object* of a verb. In this case, the verb is *to be*. Here’s a simple example:

> It is I.
>
> It is me.

Using *I* sounds perhaps more formal, but also less natural, so use *me* if you’re writing as you would speak. *Myself* is normally used with a reflexive verb, where the object of the action is also the subject:

> I take care of myself.

However, *myself/yourself/&c.* are also frequently used as more formal alternatives to *me/you/&c.*, especially in lists of people. Some object to it as a matter of style, but I think it’s also acceptable. When in doubt, choose *me*:

> We are a family of four: my father, my mother, my brother, and me.