# It's ideal for "you" or "yourselves"

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it correct to use “yourself” and “myself” (versus “you” and “me”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me)

Are both *It's ideal for **you*** and *It's ideal for **yourselves*** grammatically correct? If not, why certain persons use 'you' while other ones use 'yourselves'?

Comment: Can you provide more context, especially for your second example since you have seen it used?  *For you* is absolutely correct in general.

Comment: Many people use English reflexives as a way of sounding more formal, non-threatening, official, or deferential than a regular personal pronoun. Longer words sound more impressive, other things being equal. And words that are inflected funny, and practically incapable of being used correctly, like *[whom](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html), whichsoever,* or *yourselves* are the most impressive of all.
So phrases like _a person like yourself,_ instead of _a person like you_, are supposed to be impressive.

Comment: @combread ninja: 'yourselves', for example, is largely used in real estate language. Best regards, Carlo.-