# Is the reflexive pronoun in "he showed me myself" correct?

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

I heard an actor in a TV series say this:

> He showed me myself (*or* to myself)

Is this slang or correct?

(He was shown a letter by his father earlier that day.)

If any of this is correct, please explain why! I have learned that you can only use a reflexive pronoun with the subject of the sentence. The word "me" is the object here, isn't it?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what the actor actually said. Is the "or to myself" part of what he said? Certainly "He showed me myself" is correct, but it may mean a couple of things, depending on context. Please clarify to show exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: He showed me myself. He was shown a letter or something.

Comment: Why is this correct?  "Me" is the object as a personal pronoun , isn´t it?

Comment: Thanks.Do you know any link concerning this topic? I have worked through 4 grammar books in my life (for advanced learners) and never read anything about this at all.

Comment: Related: [Why is “herself” required in this particular sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189095) ...the answers seem kind of messy and confusing, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s “correct”.

(And by the way, slang **does not mean** “incorrect”. It’s a specific sort of casual vocabulary or expression, not incorrect grammar.)

> He showed me myself.

Here *me* is the indirect object and *myself* the direct object. It wouldn’t sound right to say to use *me* for both direct and indirect or prepositional as in "He showed me me" or "He showed me to me", so one of those two got swapped to *myself*.

It’s not quite true that you can only use a *-self* pronoun when the subject and object refer to the same person or thing. For one thing, the *-self* forms are also used emphatically, as in "I myself called the sheriff."

So you could think of this as a form of emphasis to distinguish the two pronouns so it doesn’t sound clunky. All these variants would be understandable in a way that the doubled *me* version would not:

- He showed me myself.
- He showed me to myself.
- He showed myself to me.
- He showed me my own self.
- He showed me to my own self.

Those all pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Wow, this is really complicated. I tried to understand but I still failed. What if said: He showed me himself.   I am not a native speaker. I do understand the emphasizing by using the reflexive pronoun as in " I met the king himself" or your example with the sheriff but not this one....!

Comment: @MarcinNowak "He showed me himself" could mean "He himself showed me (something)" or it could mean "He showed himself to me". In speech, intonation would make clear which of those was meant but the second would be unusual.

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don´t understand why you would say "me me". I should mean his father showed the letter to him.  Did I get the meaning wrong?

Comment: I looked up the direct and indirect object as well as the prepositional one. My mother tongue is German, and we don´t have these terms when it comes to objects. We define by case only. I could rephrase my question by saying " what´s the point in knowing about these different object types" other than identifying parts of a sentence( here and in general)? I can´t understand the importance here. I feel stupid ....

Comment: @MarcinNowak Indirect object is dative, direct object is accusative. I’m sure you would have no problem with having both kinds of object in the same utterance like *Er hat mir den Schlüssel gezeigt* in German, right? I don’t know German well enough to say whether *Er hat mir selbst gezeigt* or *Er hat mir mich gezeigt* (that doesn't look right) or some such makes any sense; I suspect that you would have as much trouble pairing *mich* and *mir* in the same utterance as you (or anyone really; it's a weird thing) are having with both of *me* and *me/myself* appearing together as distinct objects.

Comment: Yes, both object types in one sentence is no problem in German. We would say: Er hat "es" (it) mir selbst gezeigt.  When you say "Er hat mir selbst gezeigt, something must follow, like "how to do this and that.   To pair mich and mir is indeed strange. You could say " Er zeigte mich mir". He showed me who I am, physically or psychologically speaking. My problem is that I just don´t understand  what "He showed me myself" actually means in German....Does it mean that he really showed me indeed?

Comment: @MarcinNowak To be perfectly honest, my suspicion is that it's just as confusing in English, so I bet that your confusion in German perfectly reveals an equal confusion in English. I'd honestly need to read or hear the entire sentence in its original context to understand it. Could it have been something like "He showed me my letter to myself"? Because then all of "my letter to myself" would be the accusative direct object. We don't usually use a 1st or 2nd person direct object in conjunction with a 1st or 2nd person indirect one. "He showed you us" and "He showed us you" are both weird.

Comment: I´ll try to find part of the series I recently watched. "Taboo", by the way...Thomas Hardy...