# "such as yourselves" or "such as you"

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronouns, reflexives

Would it be

> *Without patrons such as yourselves, we could not have this event.*

OR

> *Without patrons such as you, we could not have this event.*

Comment: It's *you*. Search *reflexive pronoun*.

Comment: It's definitely *yinz*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, J Shearin. Please include a brief summary of what you've discovered from your own research into the question you've asked here; that way, answerers won't repeat work you've already done. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it correct to use "yourself" and "myself" (versus "you" and "me")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me)

Answer (score -1):

**The word 'patrons' is in plural so that infers 'yourselves' is correct.**

*Sorry, my reputation is low to post a comment.*

Comment: Hi, Bonga, **you** is also plural. Your post doesn't answer the question. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. You can ask a question or answer new questions to get reputation points. But please don't answer any question this way.