# Which is proper "you" or "yourself" in the sentence included in the body?

Tags: word-choice

The interview pool was very competitive, with all candidates, including you, presenting impressive strengths, talents and experience.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me

Comment: The sentence reads exclusively as a classsic setup for "Unfortunately, we had to make choices and went another way." Flattery with neither you nor yourself softens that expectation.