# Can you tell me if the "ask for myself should be ask for me

Tags: grammaticality

If you have questions, please feel free to ask for myself or Cory to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it correct to use "yourself" and "myself" (versus "you" and "me")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use "me" rather than "myself". Other people will be asking you; you aren't going to be asking yourself. Use "myself", "yourself", etc. only when the same person performs and receives some action.

Also, there is a style rule about including your own pronoun last in a list, so you may want to consider "Cory or me". However, if you want people to ask you first and then to ask Cory as an second choice, you may want to leave it "me or Cory".

Lastly, you may want to consider revising the sentence. You use "question" twice and "ask" twice, which seems a bit overly complicated. Something like this would be much more concise with the same meaning:

> Please feel free to ask Cory or me any questions you may have.